# UITextView in UiCollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I really need your help here. I have a UITextView in a UiCollectionViewCell. The problem i am facing here is when i select the cell to edit it , neither the textview methods nor the collectionview methods are called. For ex. neither the didSelectItemAtIndexPath nor the textViewDidBeginEditing methods are invoked. 
As a result, I am not able to capture the edits made by the user the cell and save it .

Any inputs would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Show your code so we can help.

Comment: Did you set the delegate of your uitextfields?

Comment: I would say, follow this example (it's tableview, but it should be almost same) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11513719/managing-delegate-of-uitextfields-in-custom-uitableviewcell

Answer (score 0):

I had faced similar problem in custom cell what i did was I had added following code to capture the events

```
  [textField addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"contentSize" options:(NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew) context:NULL];

  -(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
      UITextView *tv = object;
     //Your code using tv
}
```

Comment: Isn't adding observers for each textfield's contentsize a little overkill? Delegates should work well ...

Comment: This was the code used for UITableView where i was using custom cell. This will depend on the requirement if you need to add dynamic textview inside tableview cell you will need this observer.

Comment: I agree that for getting textview size, this is valid approach. However OP wanted to track methods like did begin editing, which has nothing to do with size